# Sparklyr : sql temporary error : argument is not interpretable as logical

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

Hi I'm new to sparklyr and I'm essentially running a query to create a temporary object in spark.

The code is something like

```
ts_data<-tbl(sc,"db.table") %>% filter(condition) %>% compute("ts_data")
```

sc is my spark connection.

I have run the same code before and it works but now I get the following error.

> Error in if (temporary) sql("TEMPORARY ") :    argument is not
> interpretable as logical

I have tried changing filters, tried it with new tables, R versions and snapshots. Yet it still gives the same exact error. I am positive there are no syntax errors

Can someone help me understand how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Changing `compute("x")` to `compute(name = "x")` fixed it for me.

This was a [bug](https://spark.rstudio.com/news/index.html#data) of sparklyr, and is fixed with version 1.7.0. So either use matching by argument (name = x) or update your sparklyr version.